# How to repaint QWidget encapsulated in QDeclarativeItem in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt4.8

I work in a C++/QML environment and I use Qt 4.8 with QtQuick 1.0.

I have a QWidget derivated class, [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/introduction), and I encapsulated it in a custom QDeclarativeItem derived class. I use a QGraphicsProxyWidget to embed the QWidget, and it appears nicely upon creation. I would like to update the chart periodically, but I simply cannot, no matter what I do it stays however I initiated it in the constructor.

Here is the code (somewhat simplified) I have:

flowgrafik.h:

```
class FlowGrafik : public QDeclarativeItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FlowGrafik(QDeclarativeItem *parent = 0);
    ~FlowGrafik();

    void addFlow(double flow);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QCustomPlot * customPlot;
    QGraphicsProxyWidget * proxy;
    QVector<double> x, y;

};
```

flowgrafik.cpp:

```
FlowGrafik::FlowGrafik(QDeclarativeItem *parent) : QDeclarativeItem(parent)
{
    customPlot = new QCustomPlot();
    proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(this);
    proxy->setWidget(customPlot);
    this->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents, false);
    customPlot->setGeometry(0,0,200,200);

    /* WHAT I WRITE HERE WILL BE DISPLAYED */

    // pass data points to graph:
    customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);

    customPlot->replot();


}

FlowGrafik::~FlowGrafik()
{
    delete customPlot;
}

void FlowGrafik::addFlow(double flow)
{
    //THIS PART DOES NOT GET DISPLAYED
    for (int i=0; i<99; ++i)
    {
      y[i] = y[i+1];
    }
    y[99] = flow;
    customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
    customPlot->replot();
    this->update();
}
```

mainview.qml:

```
Rectangle {
    id: flowGrafik
    objectName: "flowGrafik"
    x: 400
    y: 40
    width: 200
    height: 200
    radius: 10
    FlowGrafik {
        id: flowGrafikItem
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could tell me why my QCustomPlot QWidget does not replot.

Comment: Does `QCustomPlot::replot` correctly `update` the underlying `QWidget`? If `replot` doesn't call `QWidget::update`, nothing will happen in the declarative item.

Comment: Why do you reimplement `paint` in `FlowGrafik`? The Child `QGraphicsProxyWidget` already does the painting of your `customPlot`. Make sure that the `customPlot` works correctly as a stand-alone widget without any graphics scene/QML involved.

Comment: To be honest I'm new to Qt, hence the confusion. I only reimplemented paint, because I found an example code [here](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/support/forum/172), and I read that it might be necessary, but I'll delete that part if you say it's superfluous.

Comment: And `QCustomPlot::replot()` has to correctly update the underlying `QWidget`, because it is a well written and documented library (not my work). But what is the best way to check this? I always deploy my code to the embedded linux system we use, and on its touch display it won't update.

Comment: it seems the example you've been using is relevant to Qt5 + QtQuick 2 (which doesn't support `QGraphicsProxyWidget`).You don't have to  reimplement `paint` method, `QCustomPlot::replot()` properly updates widget. There can be troubles with mouse interracton, though.

Comment: You are right. I deleted the reimplementation of `paint` but it still doesn't update. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing a small test case that reproduces the issue. Target ~150 lines of a single file `main.cpp`.

Comment: I think I am missing a command from the C++ code that would make my QML Item replot.

Comment: @AndreiR. I made a small test case, and the widget turned out to be working properly. I could save its pixmap to a file, and the graph looks just as I expect it to look like. Furthermore I found out that neither the QDeclarativeItem::update() nor anything else calls the paint method, therefore the item stays as constructed. Could the root of the problem be, that I load my QML file into a QmlApplicationViewer? Could you suggest something else instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the solution was to create a pointer in the C++ code that points at the QML item.

I accidentally created an other instance in the C++, modified that one, and expected the QML instance to change.

```
QDeclarativeView mainView;
mainView.setSource(QUrl("qrc:///qml/qml/mainview.qml"));
Flowgrafik * flowGrafik = mainView.rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>(QString("flowGrafikItem"));
//or if Flowgrafik was the main element: Flowgrafik * flowGrafik = mainView.rootObject();
flowGrafik->addFlow(x);
```